# activation=tf.keras.activations.relu vs activation='relu'

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, neural-network, keras, tensorflow

Both models are for binary classification problems

**Model 1**

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model_1 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation='relu'),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model_1.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model_1.fit(X, y, epochs=250)
```

**Model 2**

```
tf.random.set_seed(42)

model_2 = tf.keras.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(4, activation=tf.keras.activations.relu),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1)
])


model_2.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.Adam(learning_rate=0.001),
                metrics=['accuracy'])


history = model_2.fit(X, y, epochs=250)
```

Both models perform differently, **model 1** performs with 0.5 accuracy and **model 2** performs with 0.85-0.9ish accuracy. I'm confused why it's different. For **model 1**, I'd say the recent why it's performing bad is because I didn't define the output activation function. However, why does **model 2** perform well despite not including the output activation function?

Comment: Are those accuracies consistent across multiple trainings of the same model? (note that `tf.random.set_seed` is not enough to ensure reproducibility, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60058588/674487); instead, consider using [tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed))

Comment: Yeah it seems that it's not consistently poor, I just got unlucky and tested model 1 a few times and got all 0.5ish and model 2 a few times and only got a few bad ones. After setting the seed, the results are exactly the same

Comment: I added an answer so that this question can be marked as resolved.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your results were probably result of the randomness in the training. Both `activation=tf.keras.activations.relu` and `activation='relu'` are equivalent.

To obtain reproducible results, consider using [`tf.keras.utils.set_random_seed`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/utils/set_random_seed) instead of `tf.random.set_seed`, because the latter is not enough (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60058588/674487)).